# Removing 'dominated' rows from a Pandas dataframe (rows with all values lower than the values of any other row)

Tags: pandas, filter

Edit: changed example df for clarity

I have a dataframe, similar to the one given below (except the real one has a few thousand rows and columns, and values being floats):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[6,5,4,3,8], [6,5,4,3,6], [1,1,3,9,5], [0,1,2,7,4], [2, 0, 0, 4, 0])

    0   1   2   3   4
0   6   5   4   3   8
1   6   5   4   3   6
2   1   1   3   9   5
3   0   1   2   7   4
4   2   0   0   4   0
```

From this dataframe, I would like to drop all rows for which all values are lower than or equal to any other row. For this simple example, row 1 and row 3 should be deleted ('dominated' by row 0 and row 2 respectively'):

```
filtered df:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   6   5   4   3   8
2   1   1   3   9   5
4   2   0   0   4   0
```

It would be even better if the approach could take into account floating point errors, since my real dataframe contains floats (i.e. instead of dropping rows where all values are lower/equal, the values shouldn't be lower than a small amount (e.g. 0.0001).

My initial idea to tackle this problem was as follows:

1. Select the first row
2. Compare the other rows with it using a list comprehension (see below)
3. Drop all rows that returned True
4. Repeat for the next row

List comprehension code:

```
selected_row = df.loc[0
[(df.loc[r]<=selected_row).all() and (df.loc[r]<selected_row).any() for r in range(len(df))]
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

This seems hardly efficient however. Any suggestions on how to (efficiently) tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a new record: `4  0 0 0 0 0`, do the output will be the same as your actual input?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you refering to the list comprehension code I posted at the end?

Comment: Add new line to your input dataframe with all zeroes. What is the expect output? All other rows dominate this last record, it's right?

Comment: Yes, such a row should be removed

Comment: You're trying to compare every row to every other? Or a specific row to the entire DataFrame?

Comment: Every row to every other (for each row, I want to delete it if there is any other row that is better/at least as good for all columns)

Comment: You do not necessarily need to do all the comparisons. In some cases you even can't do them in memory. Can you give more details on the limits of you real life data? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68528943/16343464) for a slower but more robust solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [6, 5, 4, 3, 8], [6, 5, 4, 3, 6], [1, 1, 3, 9, 5],
    [0, 1, 2, 7, 4], [2, 0, 0, 4, 0]
])

# Need to ensure only one of each row present since comparing to 1
# there needs to be one and only one of each row
df = df.drop_duplicates()

# Broadcasted comparison explanation below
cmp = (df.values[:, None] <= df.values).all(axis=2).sum(axis=1) == 1

# Filter using the results from the comparison
df = df[cmp]
```

`df`:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  6  5  4  3  8
2  1  1  3  9  5
4  2  0  0  4  0
```

---

Intuition:

Broadcast the comparison operation over the DataFrame:

```
(df.values[:, None] <= df.values)
```

```
[[[ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True False]
  [False False False  True False]
  [False False False  True False]
  [False False False  True False]]  # df vs [6 5 4 3 8]

 [[ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [False False False  True False]
  [False False False  True False]
  [False False False  True False]]  # df vs [6 5 4 3 6]

 [[ True  True  True False  True]
  [ True  True  True False  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [False  True False False False]
  [ True False False False False]]  # df vs [1 1 3 9 5]

 [[ True  True  True False  True]
  [ True  True  True False  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]
  [ True False False False False]]  # df vs [0 1 2 7 4]

 [[ True  True  True False  True]
  [ True  True  True False  True]
  [False  True  True  True  True]
  [False  True  True  True  True]
  [ True  True  True  True  True]]]  # df vs [2 0 0 4 0]
```

Then we can check for [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) on `axis=2`:

```
(df.values[:, None] <= df.values).all(axis=2)
```

```
[[ True False False False False]   # Rows le [6 5 4 3 8]
 [ True  True False False False]   # Rows le [6 5 4 3 6]
 [False False  True False False]   # Rows le [1 1 3 9 5]
 [False False  True  True False]   # Rows le [0 1 2 7 4]
 [False False False False  True]]  # Rows le [2 0 0 4 0]
```

Then we can use [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) to total how many rows are less than or equal to:

```
(df.values[:, None] <= df.values).all(axis=2).sum(axis=1)
```

```
[1 2 1 2 1]
```

The rows where the is only 1 row that is less than or equal to (self match only) are the rows to keep. Because we [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) there will be no duplicates in the dataframe so the only `True` values will be the self-match and those that are less than or equal to:

```
(df.values[:, None] <= df.values).all(axis=2).sum(axis=1) == 1
```

```
[ True False  True False  True]
```

This then becomes the filter for the DataFrame:

```
df = df[[True, False, True, False, True]]
```

`df`:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  6  5  4  3  8
2  1  1  3  9  5
4  2  0  0  4  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and the explanation. I added one row in my example df since some of the other replies did not handle that row correctly (yours did).

Comment: And if I understand correctly, I could adapt your code to the following to handle float errors: cmp = (df.values[:, None]-0.0001 <= df.values).all(axis=2).sum(axis=1) == 1
df = df[cmp]

Comment: Could my addition lead to problems/undesireable results if I were to apply it this way?

Comment: I think subtracting is fine but I would use `(df.values - 0.0001)[:, None]` to subtract before broadcasting. If they were equal they will now be less than so that's okay. And if they were not equal to because of being within `0.001` they will now be equal or less than. So I think that works.

Comment: Maybe it would be better/safer to first round all values of the dataframe, and then apply your solution afterwards. Thanks for your help & replies :)

Answer (score 2):

What is the expected proportion of dominant rows?
What is the size of the datasets that you will handle and the available memory?

While a solution like the [broadcasting approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522718/16343464) is very clever and efficient (vectorized), it will not be able to handle large dataframes as the size of the broadcast will quickly explode the memory limit (a 100,000×10 input array will **not** run on most computers).

Here is another approach to avoid testing all combinations and computing everything at once in the memory. It is slower due to the loop, but it should be able to handle much larger arrays. It will also run faster when the proportion of dominated rows increases.

In summary, it compares the dataset with the first row, drops the dominated rows, shifts the first row to the end and start again until doing a full loop. If rows get dropped over time, the number of comparison decrease.

```
def get_dominants_loop(df):
    from tqdm import tqdm
    seen = [] # keep track of tested rows
    idx = df.index # initial index
    for i in tqdm(range(len(df)+1)):
        x = idx[0]
        if x in seen:   # done a full loop
            return df.loc[idx]
        seen.append(idx[0])
        # check which rows are dominated and drop them from the index
        idx = (df.loc[idx]-df.loc[x]).le(0).all(axis=1)
        # put tested row at the end
        idx = list(idx[~idx].index)+[x]
```

To drop the dominated rows:

```
df = get_dominants_loop(df)
```

*NB. I used [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) here to have a progress bar. It is not needed for the code to run*

Quick benchmarking in cases where the broadcast approach could not run: <2min for 100k×10 in a cas where most rows are not dominated ; 4s when most rows are dominated

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 16GB RAM on my device. My dataframe dimensions will be around 1000 x  4000. I haven't tested either of the solutions on the final df yet because I don't have it yet (I should have it by the end of this week latest). Hence I also don't know yet the proportion of dominated rows, but I do expected it will be more than 50% of the dataset

Comment: I really appreciate the scalability of your solution. I will give an update regarding the performance of both methods for my problem later :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```py
df[df.shift(1)[0] >= df[1][0]]
```

**output**

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 9 | 5 |

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately your code doesn't give the answer I'm looking for (it keeps row 1 instead of row 0; for which the last column is 8 instead of 6).

Comment: sorry, modify `df.shift(1)[0] `

Comment: This still gives the same output for me (it keeps row 1 instead of row 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
# Cartesian product
x = np.tile(df, df.shape[0]).reshape(-1, df.shape[1])
y = np.tile(df.T, df.shape[0]).T

# Remove same rows
#dups = np.all(x == y, axis=1)
#x = x[~dups]
#y = y[~dups]
x = np.delete(x, slice(None, None, df.shape[0]+1), axis=0)
y = np.delete(y, slice(None, None, df.shape[0]+1), axis=0)

# Keep dominant rows
m = x[np.all(x >= y, axis=1)]
```

```
>>> m
array([[6, 5, 4, 3, 8],
       [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]])
```

```
# Before remove duplicates
# df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x.tolist(), 'y': y.tolist()})
>>> df1
                  x                y
0   [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]  # dup
1   [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]  # DOMINANT
2   [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]  [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]
3   [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]
4   [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]
5   [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]  # dup
6   [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]  [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]
7   [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]
8   [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]
9   [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]
10  [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]  [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]  # dup
11  [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]  # DOMINANT
12  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 8]
13  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]  [6, 5, 4, 3, 6]
14  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]  [1, 1, 3, 9, 5]
15  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]  [0, 1, 2, 7, 4]  # dup
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does remove [2, 0, 0, 4, 0] however, which isnt dominated by either [6, 5, 4, 3, 8] (column 3), nor by [1, 1, 3, 9, 5] (column 0)

Comment: @bprsch. I updated my answer to avoid remove two identical rows at different index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `df.apply()`

```
m = (pd.concat(df.apply(lambda x: df.ge(x,axis=1),axis=1).tolist(),keys = df.index)
.all(axis=1)
.groupby(level=0)
.sum()
.eq(1))

ndf = df.loc[m]
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  6  5  4  3  8
2  1  1  3  9  5
4  2  0  0  4  0
```