# Pandas drop rows lower then others in all colums

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a dataframe with a lot of rows with numerical columns, such as:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 7 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I need to reduce the size of the dataframe by removing those rows that has another row with all values bigger.
In the previous example i need to remove the last row because the first row has all values bigger (in case of dubplicate rows i need to keep one of them).
And return This:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 7 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

My faster solution are the folowing:

```
    def complete_reduction(df, columns):
        def _single_reduction(row):
            df["check"] = True
            for col in columns:
                df["check"] = df["check"] & (df[col] >= row[col])
            drop_index.append(df["check"].sum() == 1)
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=columns)
        drop_index = []
        df.apply(lambda x: _single_reduction(x), axis=1)
        df = df[numpy.array(drop_index).astype(bool)]
        return df
```

Any better ideas?

---

Update:

A new solution has been found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68528943/11327160
but i hope for somethings faster.

Comment: How many columns/rows do you have in practice? It seems the speed of the proposed algorithms is very dependent of the shape of the dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An more memory-efficient and faster solution than the one proposed so far is to use **Numba**. There is no need to create huge temporary array with Numba. Moreover, it is easy to write a *parallel implementation* that makes use of all CPU cores. Here is the implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def is_dominated(arr, k):
    n, m = arr.shape
    for i in range(n):
        if i != k:
            dominated = True
            for j in range(m):
                if arr[i, j] < arr[k, j]:
                    dominated = False
            if dominated:
                return True
    return False

# Precompile the function to native code for the most common types
@nb.njit(['(i4[:,::1],)', '(i8[:,::1],)'], parallel=True, cache=True)
def dominated_rows(arr):
    n, m = arr.shape
    toRemove = np.empty(n, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        toRemove[i] = is_dominated(arr, i)
    return toRemove

# Special case
df2 = df.drop_duplicates()

# Main computation
result = df2[~dominated_rows(np.ascontiguousarray(df.values))]
```

---

### Benchmark

The input test is two random dataframes of shape 20000x5 and 5000x100 containing small integers (ie. `[0;100[`). Tests have been done on a (6-core) i5-9600KF processor with 16 GiB of RAM on Windows. The version of @BingWang is the updated one of the 2022-05-24. Here are performance results of the proposed approaches so far:

```py
Dataframe with shape 5000x100
 - Initial code:   114_340 ms
 - BENY:             2_716 ms  (consume few GiB of RAM)
 - Bing Wang:        2_619 ms
 - Numba:              303 ms  <----

Dataframe with shape 20000x5
 - Initial code:    (too long)
 - BENY:             8.775 ms  (consume few GiB of RAM)
 - Bing Wang:          578 ms
 - Numba:               21 ms  <----
```

This solution is respectively about **9 to 28 times faster** than the fastest one (of @BingWang). It also has the benefit of **consuming far less memory**. Indeed, the @BENY implementation consume few GiB of RAM while this one (and the one of @BingWang) only consumes no more than few MiB for this used-case. The speed gain over the @BingWang implementation is due to the *early stop*, parallelism and the native execution.

One can see that this Numba implementation and the one of @BingWang are quite efficient when the number of column is small. This makes sense for the @BingWang since the complexity should be `O(N(logN)^(d-2))` where `d` is the number of columns. As for Numba, it is significantly faster because most rows are dominated on the second random dataset causing the early stop to be very effective in practice. I think the @BingWang algorithm might be faster when most rows are not dominated. However, this case should be very uncommon on dataframes with few columns and a lot of rows (at least, clearly on uniformly random ones).

Comment: Upvoting for suggesting a "series" implementation that gets effectively parallelized thanks to numba. Unlike multiprocessing, memory is shared much more efficiently

Comment: hi Jerome, I have cleaned up my code and got rid of a performance bug. It now runs a lot (5-10x) faster and handles high dimension cases very well. I totally agree if the time is acceptable, we should not trade time complexity with more complexity in code. So just for your record. Thanks for bringing up the solution

Comment: @BingWang I added a more complete benchmark including your updated version (results are a bit different from the previous one because the environment unfortunately changed since). It is now a bit faster than the one of BENY (I think it was slower before).

Comment: @BingWang I tested another shape of dataframe to check if your implementation could be faster on it and it turns out results are pretty interesting (see the end of the answer) though the Numba implementation is still (unexpectedly) faster.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I tested on larger N. At Dimension=1000, N=20000 (1 min), N=100,000 (10 min) and N=200,000 (31 min). So  the growth of time appears to be less than N^2 but larger than N, consistent with the paper. (Jupyter i7-3770k, you PC is horribly better than mine:) So now we just need a huge N to show this algorithm is useful.

Comment: @BingWang Interesting. Note that for a dataframe with N=20_000, D was set to 5 and not 1000 in my benchmark. This certainly explain why the execution is much slower on your machine (20x times slower). The performance of a i7-3770k and a i5-9600KF should not be so different on your code (your processor should certainly be no more than 50% slower).

Comment: Yeah single core should be about the same between the CPUs. The 'better' mostly is energy efficiency

Answer (score 5):

We can do `numpy` board cast

```
s = df.values
out = df[np.sum(np.all(s>=s[:,None],-1),1)==1]
Out[44]: 
    A  B  C  D
0  12  7  1  0
1   7  1  2  0
2   1  1  1  1
```

Comment: While I agree this is beautiful, it looks O(N^2) to me. It can be done in O(NlogN) in general by finding the convex hull.

Comment: Ty for the solution. It is fuster than mine, but unluckily it need to create a nXn Matrix that i'am unable to handle. Any other idea?

Comment: @BingWang can you explain a bit more your comment? It intrigues me

Comment: @ZaeroDivide Sorry my thought was wrong. What I found later was Kung et al 1975 http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~htk/publication/1975-jacm-kung-luccio-preparata.pdf which shows a way of O(N(logN)^(d-2)). I am not sure if people made more progress after that.

Comment: @stefanogelli If you can work with time O(N^2), the space cost is just O(N) if just do a loop instead of vectorization

Comment: @BingWang Thank you for the reference. I am not an algorithm guy so any new knowledge is welcome. As usual you can chose space or time but not both.

Comment: I'll try to implement the solution proposed by Kung or there is a version already implemented in Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try based on Kung et al 1975
[http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~htk/publication/1975-jacm-kung-luccio-preparata.pdf](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Ehtk/publication/1975-jacm-kung-luccio-preparata.pdf)

Brutal force solution is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68528943/11327160

I didn't robustly test it, but using these parameters it looks to be the same answer

There is no guarantee it is correct, or I am even following the paper. Please test thoroughly. In addition, there is very likely to be a commercial solution to calculate it.

```
D=5 #dimension, or number of columns
N=2000 #number of data rows
M=1000 #upper bound for random integers
```

Changing to D=20 and N=20000 you can see Kung75 completes in <1 minute but Brutal Force will use more than 10x the time.
Even at Dimension=1000,Rows=20000,value range 0~999, it can still complete slightly over 1 minute

This can be revised similar to merge sort (compute small chunks by brutal force, then merge up with Filter), which is easier to switch to parallel computing.
Another way of speeding up is to turn off array boundary check after you are comfortable with the code. This is due to heavy array indexing here. I would recommend C# if you want to try this path.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

#generate fake data
D=1000 #dimension, or number of columns
N=20000 #number of data rows
M=1000 #upper bound for random integers

np.random.seed(12345) #set seed so this is reproducible
data=np.random.randint(0,M,(N,D))
for i in range(0,12):
    print(i,data[i])

#Compare w and v starting dimention d
def Compare(w,v,d=0):
    cmp=3 #0x11, low bit is GE, high bit is LE, together means EQ
    while d<D:
        if w[d]>v[d]:
            cmp&=1
        elif w[d]<v[d]:
            cmp&=2
        if cmp>0:
            d+=1
        else:
            break
    return cmp # 0=uncomparable, 1=GT, 2=LT, 3=EQ
#unit test:
#print(Compare(data[0],data[1]))
#print(Compare(data[0],data[1],4))
#print(Compare(data[1],data[11]))
#print(Compare(data[11],data[1]))
#print(Compare(data[1],data[1]))
def AuxSort(d,ndxArray): #stable sort desc by dimention d
    return [x[1] for x in sorted([(-data[n][d],n) for n in ndxArray])]
#unit test
#print(AuxSort(data,0,[0,4,3]))
#print(AuxSort(data,2,[0,1,2]))
#cumulatively find the pareto front. Time O(N^2), space O(N)
def N2BrutalForce(data,ndxArray=None,d=0):
    if len(data)==0:
        return []
    if not ndxArray: #by default check the entire data
        ndxArray=list(range(len(data)))
    #up to this point ndxArray is not empty
    result={ndxArray[0]:data[ndxArray[0]]}
    for i in range(1,len(ndxArray)):
        dominated=[]
        j=ndxArray[i]
        for k,v in result.items():
            c=Compare(data[j],v,d)
            if c>1:
                break
            elif c==1:
                dominated.append(k)
        else:
            for o in dominated:
                del result[o]
            result[j]=data[j]
    return [r for r in result]
def resultPrinter(res, ShowCountOnly=False):
    if not ShowCountOnly:
        for r in sorted(res):
            print(r,data[r])
    print(len(res),'results found',datetime.datetime.today())
#unit rest
#resultPrinter(N2BrutalForce(data),True)
#resultPrinter(N2BrutalForce(data,list(range(15))))
def FindT(R1,R2,S1,S2,d):
    S1R1=set(Filter(data,d,R1,S1))
    T1=[s for s in S1 if s in S1R1]
    S2R1=Filter(data,d+1,R1,S2)
    S2R2=set(Filter(data,d,R2,S2))
    T2=[s for s in S2R1 if s in S2R2]
    return T1+T2
def BreakAtPseudoMedian(sArray,d):
    sArray=AuxSort(d,sArray) #this could speed up by moving the sort to caller and avoid redo sorting
    if data[sArray[0]][d]==data[sArray[-1]][d]:
        return [],sArray
    L=len(sArray)
    mHigh=mLow=L//2
    while mLow>0 and data[sArray[mLow]][d]==data[sArray[mLow-1]][d]:
        mLow-=1
    if mLow>0:
        return sArray[:mLow],sArray[mLow:]
    while mHigh<L-1 and data[sArray[mHigh]][d]==data[sArray[mHigh+1]][d]:
        mHigh+=1
    return sArray[:mHigh],sArray[mHigh:]
def Filter(data,d,rArray,sArray):
    L=len(rArray)+len(sArray)
    if d==D-1 and rArray:
        R=max(data[r][d] for r in rArray)
        return [s for s in sArray if data[s][d]>R]
    elif len(rArray)*len(sArray)<=30 or len(rArray)<=2 or len(sArray)<=2:
        nonDominated=[]
        for s in sArray:
            for r in rArray:
                c=Compare(data[s],data[r],d)
                if c>1:
                    break
            else:
                nonDominated.append(s)
        return nonDominated
    S1,S2=BreakAtPseudoMedian(sArray,d)
    R1,R2=BreakAtRefValue(rArray,d,data[S2[0]][d])
    if not S1 and not R1:
        return Filter(data,d+1,rArray,sArray)
    return FindT(R1,R2,S1,S2,d)
#Filter(data,0,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[11])
def BreakAtRefValue(rArray,d,br):
    rArray=AuxSort(d,rArray)
    if data[rArray[0]][d]<=br:
        return [],rArray
    if data[rArray[-1]][d]>br:
        return rArray,[]
    mLow,mHigh=0,len(rArray)-1
    while mLow<mHigh-1 and data[rArray[mLow]][d]>br and data[rArray[mHigh]][d]<br:
        mid=(mLow+mHigh)//2
        if data[rArray[mid]][d]>br:
            mLow=mid
        elif data[rArray[mid]][d]<br:
            mHigh=mid
        else:
            mLow=mid
            break
    if data[rArray[mLow]][d]>br and data[rArray[mHigh]][d]<br:
        return rArray[:mHigh],rArray[mHigh:]
    if data[rArray[mLow]][d]==br:
        while data[rArray[mLow-1]][d]==br:
            mLow-=1
        return rArray[:mLow],rArray[mLow:]
    while data[rArray[mHigh-1]][d]==br:
        mHigh-=1
    return rArray[:mHigh],rArray[mHigh:]
def Kung75(data,d,ndxArray):
    L=len(ndxArray)
    if L<10:
        return N2BrutalForce(data,ndxArray,d)
    elif d==D-1:
        x,y=-1,-1
        for n in ndxArray:
            if y<0 or data[n][d]>x:
                x,y=data[n][d],n
        return [y]
    if data[ndxArray[0]][d]==data[ndxArray[-1]][d]:
        return Kung75(data,d+1,AuxSort(d+1,ndxArray))
    R,S=BreakAtPseudoMedian(ndxArray,d)
    R=Kung75(data,d,R)
    S=Kung75(data,d,S)
    T=Filter(data,d+1,R,S)
    return R+T
print('started at',datetime.datetime.today())
resultPrinter(Kung75(data,0,AuxSort(0,list(range(len(data))))),True)
```

Comment: Made some corrections

Comment: Made further improvement, mostly due to a better Compare function, the speed is around minute. It also helps Brutal Force to complete less than 10 minutes. At random data, the increase of dimension is not a bottle neck, but you can still feel the impact of additional rows.

Comment: I think this implementation is pretty interesting and deserve more attention (especially for the research effort). I wonder if it can be very fast once implemented in a native language like C/C++ and used as a module, or optimized using Numba/Cython (it seems not trivial to do though).

Answer (score 0):

We take the cumulative maximum value per column in the dataframe.

We want to keep all rows that have a single column value that is equal to the maximum. We then drop duplicates using pandas drop_duplicates

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     [[12, 7, 1, 0], [7, 1, 2, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0, 0]],
    ...:     columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    ...: )

In [15]: df[(df == df.cummax(axis=0)).any(axis=1)].drop_duplicates()
Out[15]: 
    A  B  C  D
0  12  7  1  0
1   7  1  2  0
2   1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Note from your description I am not sure if you require the cummulative maximum or simply the maximum - i.e. do you compare against the entire dataframe, or only the rows above the row ?

Comment: Ty, i compare every rows with the entire dataframe. So your solution doesn't work but it  remove too many rows. Now i'm actually trying to make 2 steps the first is a faster partial reduction by sorting over different columns and check each row the only the previous one. Then i use a complete check. This help but it doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[:cutoff]
```

If this takes too long you could do it on subsets of the df until
it is small enough.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. Please read the question more carefully: the OP did not ask for the dataframe to be sorted. It can help to compute one column but not all (at least not so easily). Beside this, `cutoff` is not defined.